# Alternativa a visual studio compilar mis programas sin IDE

Tags: visual-studio

Quiero compilar mis aplicaciones en `Visual Studio` que normalmente hago en `Visual Basic` y `C#` pero sin necesidad de arrancar el `IDE` cada vez que necesito compilar.

El proyecto figuraría así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero compilarlo desde la consola no usando el `IDE` es decir desde el compilador de `Visual Studio` para desarrolladores. Para compilar hago:

```
vbc.exe Form1.vb
```

Pero no me aparece nada compilado ni nada ni parece funcionar ¿Alguna sugerencia o consejo para lograrlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque no quieres arrancar Visual Studio, voy a asumir que lo tienes instalado.

De ser el caso, cuando se instaló Visual Studio, también se instaló una consola para desarrolladores Visual Studio (ejemplo en inglés: `Developer Command Prompt for VS2015`.

Si abres esa consola, y luego navegas donde tienes tu proyecto, entonces puedes ejecutar la sentencia siguiente:

```
msbuild TCPClientClean.vbproj
```

Nota que el parámetro que le pasas a `msbuild` puede ser el archivo de proyecto (*.vbproj o *.csproj) o el archivo de solución (*.sln).